# Bash: Make a Variable out of Each Quoted String in a Block of Quoted Strings

Tags: bash, macos, shell, unix, default

I’m trying to write a script that will go over each service in the `Shortcuts > Services` section of the `Keyboard Preference Pane`, and disable it.

This is the basic command to disable a service:

```
defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add SERVICE "
<dict>
<key>enabled_context_menu</key><false/>
<key>enabled_services_menu</key><false/>
<key>key_equivalent</key><string>""</string>
</dict>
"
```

It is inefficient to get all services upfront and put them in the script, since many services are incrementally added upon installing new software. It has to be some kind of a loop.

So far, I’ve been trying to use `defaults` and `awk` to get every line that contains a service.

```
a=$(defaults read pbs NSServicesStatus | awk 'NR%5==2' ) && echo $a
```

And, this is the output:

```
"com.ScooterSoftware.BeyondCompare - Compare Files - bcCompareFiles" = { "com.ScooterSoftware.BeyondCompare - Compare Folders - bcCompareFolders" = { "com.ScooterSoftware.BeyondCompare - Select Left File for Compare - bcSelLeftFile" = { "com.ScooterSoftware.BeyondCompare - Select Left Folder for Compare - bcSelLeftFolder" = { "com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange - Send File To Bluetooth Device - sendFileUsingBluetoothOBEXService" = { "com.apple.ChineseTextConverterService - Convert Text from Simplified to Traditional Chinese - convertTextToTraditionalChinese" = { "com.apple.ChineseTextConverterService - Convert Text from Traditional to Simplified Chinese - convertTextToSimplifiedChinese" = { "com.apple.ChineseTextConverterService - Convert Text to Full Width - convertTextToFullWidth" = { "com.apple.ChineseTextConverterService - Convert Text to Half Width - convertTextToHalfWidth" = { "com.apple.Dictionary - Look Up in Dictionary - doLookupService" = { "com.apple.FolderActionsSetup - Folder Actions Setup - openFilesFromPasteboard" = { "com.apple.Grab - Capture Selection from Screen - variableSelection" = { "com.apple.ImageCaptureService - Import Image - ImportImage" = { "com.apple.QuickTime.service.encodeSelectedAudioFiles - Encode Selected Audio Files - runWorkflowAsService" = { "com.apple.Safari - Add to Reading List - addToReadingList" = { "com.apple.Safari - Search With %WebSearchProvider@ - searchWithWebSearchProvider" = { "com.apple.ScriptEditor2 - Script Editor/Get Result of AppleScript - runAsAppleScript" = { "com.apple.SpotlightService - SEARCH_WITH_SPOTLIGHT - doSearchWithSpotlight" = { "com.apple.Stickies - Make Sticky - makeStickyFromTextService" = { "com.apple.Terminal - New Terminal Tab at Folder - newTerminalAtFolder" = { "com.apple.Terminal - New Terminal at Folder - newTerminalAtFolder" = { "com.apple.Terminal - Open man Page in Terminal - openManPage" = { "com.apple.Terminal - Search man Page Index in Terminal - searchManPages" = { "com.apple.finder - Finder/Open - open" = { "com.apple.finder - Finder/Reveal - reveal" = { "com.apple.finder - Finder/Show Info - showInfo" = { "com.apple.mail - Mail/New Email To Address - mailTo" = { "com.apple.mail - Mail/New Email With Selection - mailSelection" = { "com.apple.services.addToiTunesAsSpokenTrack - Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track - runWorkflowAsService" = { "com.apple.services.encodeSelectedVideoFiles - Encode Selected Video Files - runWorkflowAsService" = { "com.apple.services.setDesktopPicture - Set Desktop Picture - runWorkflowAsService" = { "com.apple.services.showMap - Show Map - runWorkflowAsService" = { "com.apple.systemuiserver - Open URL - openURL" = { "com.evernote.Evernote - ENApplicationServiceMenuItemTitle - serviceCreateNote" = { "com.flexibits.cardhop.mac - Send to Cardhop - sendToCardhop" = { "com.flexibits.fantastical2.mac - Send to Fantastical 2 - sendToFantastical" = { "com.houdah.HoudahSpot4 - New HoudahSpot Search - newSearch" = { "com.houdah.HoudahSpot4 - Search Folders in HoudahSpot - folderSearch" = { "com.houdah.HoudahSpot4 - Search in HoudahSpot - search" = { "com.kapeli.dashdoc - Create Snippet in Dash - createSnippetService" = { "com.kapeli.dashdoc - Look Up in Dash - lookupService" = { "net.pornel.ImageOptim - ImageOptimize - handleServices" = { }
```

Where each quoted string represents a service.

**Here are my issues:**

I’ve tried to remove all of the extraneous data and whitespaces (`=`, `{` and `}`) with this `sed` command, but couldn’t get rid of that single, trailing `}`.

```
b=$(echo $a | sed -E -e 's/ = { / /g' ) && echo "${b}"
```

Even without the trailing `}` (which would yield an error only in the last iteration anyway, or so I believe), not a single string is parsed correctly within this loop I made:

```
for service in "${b}"; do
defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add "${service}" "
<dict>
<key>enabled_context_menu</key><false/>
<key>enabled_services_menu</key><false/>
<key>key_equivalent</key><string>""</string>
</dict>
"
done
```

I used the following command just for testing, and didn’t get a valid result:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :NSServicesStatus:${service}" ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist
```

It seems like only is service is parsed correctly, and I don’t know which one:

```
Dict {
    key_equivalent = 
    enabled_context_menu = false
    enabled_services_menu = false
}
```

How do I solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: `for service in "${b}"; do` will **never** iterate more than once, with the complete contents of `b`.

Comment: BTW, is the text containing `…`s a literal quote? (We can't very well test proposed answers if we don't have exact content to run through them).

Comment: Also, note that it looks like some pieces of your code got munged by an editor inserting "smart quotes". Only `"` is parsed as syntax by bash; `“` and `”` are not.

Comment: Also, if you're using four-space indents, that means you don't need to (and shouldn't!) also insert backticks at the start and end of a segment; please ensure that code blocks are literal (which is to say, that they exactly match your original content; no extra backticks, no discrepancies between quote types; etc).

Comment: Also, consider `printf 'a=%q\n' "$a"` instead of `echo $a` or (better) `echo "$a"`. See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: why `echo $foo` is misleading.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the input. Formatting has been fixed.The  `…` wasn’t literal, I tried to imply the output is very long without flooding the post. I believe there are no smart quotes within the code — I wrote it with Sublime Text 3. I want the loop to iterate **once** every **quoted string** of "${b}”, and not "${b}” in its entirety. How do I do that?

Comment: The post still does contain smart quotes (in `'NR%5==2’`, the closing quote is a "smart quote" as well). With respect to extracting quoted strings -- personally, I would reach for `egrep -o` to emit one line per such string, which you can then iterate over with a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/iGNKCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually condone parsing or generating structured data with structure-unaware tools, but ignoring that --

```
while IFS= read -r service; do
  service=${service%'"'}; service=${service#'"'}
  defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add "${service}" '
  <dict>
  <key>enabled_context_menu</key><false/>
  <key>enabled_services_menu</key><false/>
  <key>key_equivalent</key><string>""</string>
  </dict>
  '
done < <(egrep -o '"[^"]+"' <<<"$a")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Charles, your script works. I was looking to test and see and that each service is printed out correctly, so I tried to put `echo “${service}”` inside the `while` loop, but all I get is a single whitespaces wrapped in quotes, many times over. In addition: How should I define `${b}` in your script? And, for the sake of learning — if you could elaborate some more on what did you do exactly in your answer, it would be very very appreciated!

Comment: I already had quote-stripping on the ideone.com version (added as a link in the comments on the question); added it here as well. The intended input is the original `$a`, not `$b`; that was a thinko. BTW, consider getting in a habit of using `declare -p service` or `printf '%q=%q\n' service "$service"` instead of `echo "$service"`; `echo` is [buggy by specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) (see the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

Comment: HI @Charles Duffy! Sorry for bumping this old question (and thanks again for answering), but I was just curious about what you said here: _"parsing or generating structured data with structure-unaware tools”_. If by “structure-unaware” you were referring to Bash, it’s myriad of options, and/or shell scripting in general — what would be the ideal tool to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: @voronoi, ...so, to initially give some examples of structure-aware command-line tools you can use in a bash script, `jq` knows how to deal with the structure of JSON, whereas XMLStarlet or xsltproc know how to deal with the structure of XML... and similarly, the Python `json` and `lxml` libraries do a *very* good job of dealing with those respective formats (and embedding a small Python script inside a larger bash script is often a reasonable choice).

Comment: @voronoi, ...see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54374721/14122 for a recent example of an answer describing how to edit an XML document with XMLStarlet; you'll see that the operations are defined in a way that refers to the document's semantics ("at the end of each wtc-server element's contents, add a wtc-import; then, for the last wtc-import in each wtc-server, add the element name..."), not to the specific text used to express those semantics.

Comment: @voronoi, ...that makes answers far more robust because they no longer care about how the data is *formatted*, but only what the data *is*; someone could change `<wtc-import>` to `< wtc-import>` and it would still work; someone could have a resource name that contains a character like `<` that has special meaning in XML, and it would still work (XMLStarlet would escape it to `&lt;` where needed); someone could take out all the semantically-insignificant whitespace from the input and it would still work; etc.

Answer (score 0):

When I understand your data correctly, you can get the services with

```
echo "$b" | tr '{' '\n' | sed -rn 's/[^"]"(.*)".*/\1/p'
```

You can echo the structure `defaults ...` using

```
echo "$b" | tr '{' '\n' | sed -rn 's/[^"]"(.*)".*/\1/p' |
   xargs -I xxx echo 'defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add "xxx" "
<dict>
<key>enabled_context_menu</key><false/>
<key>enabled_services_menu</key><false/>
<key>key_equivalent</key><string>""</string>
</dict>"
'
```

When you want to call a program `defaults`, the second `echo` can be removed.

```
echo "$b" | tr '{' '\n' | sed -rn 's/[^"]"(.*)".*/\1/p' | 
   xargs -I xxx defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add "xxx" "
<dict>
<key>enabled_context_menu</key><false/>
<key>enabled_services_menu</key><false/>
<key>key_equivalent</key><string>""</string>
</dict>"
```

Comment: Hi @Walter, I tried to test your answer, but couldn’t get it work. How should I declare `${b}` in your solution?

Comment: It should be filled with `"com.ScooterSoftware.BeyondCompare - Compare Files - bcCompareFiles" = { "com..... ImageOptimize - handleServices" = { }`