# Adding a XML element using shell or Python

Tags: python, xml, shell, awk, sed

we have a requirement to insert XML element in multiple locations

i have to insert one more element

```
<wtc-import>
      <name>WTCImportedService-0-rap01</name>
      <resource-name>XXXX01F</resource-name>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <remote-access-point-list>rap01</remote-access-point-list>
      <remote-name>XXXX01F</remote-name>
    </wtc-import>
```

in the ---INSERT WTC IMPORT SERVICE---- mentioned location in the below file

basically before the end of each < /wtc-server>  tag

```
  <wtc-server>
    <name>WTC-server-117-02</name>
    <target>cwea_117_02</target>
    <wtc-local-tux-dom>
      <name>lap01</name>
      <access-point>lap01</access-point>
      <access-point-id>wl.prodcwe117.02</access-point-id>
      <block-time>600</block-time>
      <nw-addr>//localhost:7125</nw-addr>
    </wtc-local-tux-dom>
    <wtc-remote-tux-dom>
      <name>rap01</name>
      <access-point>rap01</access-point>
      <access-point-id>tx.hello101</access-point-id>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <nw-addr>//hostanme:71105</nw-addr>
      <federation-url></federation-url>
      <federation-name></federation-name>
    </wtc-remote-tux-dom>
    <wtc-import>
      <name>WTCImportedService-0-rap01</name>
      <resource-name>XXXX01F</resource-name>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <remote-access-point-list>rap01</remote-access-point-list>
      <remote-name>XXXX01F</remote-name>
    </wtc-import>
```

**-------INSERT NEW WTC IMPORT HERE---------**

```
  </wtc-server>

  <wtc-server>
    <name>WTC-server-117-03</name>
    <target>cwea_117_03</target>
    <wtc-local-tux-dom>
      <name>lap01</name>
      <access-point>lap01</access-point>
      <access-point-id>wl.prodcwe117.02</access-point-id>
      <block-time>600</block-time>
      <nw-addr>//localhost:7125</nw-addr>
    </wtc-local-tux-dom>
    <wtc-remote-tux-dom>
      <name>rap01</name>
      <access-point>rap01</access-point>
      <access-point-id>tx.hello101</access-point-id>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <nw-addr>//hostanme:71105</nw-addr>
      <federation-url></federation-url>
      <federation-name></federation-name>
    </wtc-remote-tux-dom>
    <wtc-import>
      <name>WTCImportedService-0-rap01</name>
      <resource-name>XXXX01F</resource-name>
      <local-access-point>lap01</local-access-point>
      <remote-access-point-list>rap01</remote-access-point-list>
      <remote-name>XXXX01F</remote-name>
    </wtc-import>
```

**-------INSERT NEW WTC IMPORT HERE---------**

```
 </wtc-server>
```

Please help

Comment: uhh, *shell/Python*? That's like saying "I have a Phillips-head screw, and want to know how to embed it in a wooden plank using either a rusty fishhook or a screwdriver". You *can* do this in shell, but doing it well (read: in a way that works with all possible forms your XML input can take and guarantees valid XML output) requires either building an XSLT template for the translation and invoking `xsltproc`, or using tools like XMLStarlet that effectively put a pretty frontend on the job of building a XSLT template. Much better to implement it in Python.

Comment: BTW, "snippet" functionality in StackOverflow is basically an equivalent to JSFiddle; it's only for code that can be run in a browser. Use the `{}` button (or four-space indents, or triple-quoted segments) for all other cases where you want to put literal code in a question.

Comment: Sure @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the inputs

Comment: BTW, it helps to make sure your code is complete enough to be testable. That means including a root element, and any `xmlns` definitions that might be at the top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this in shell with XMLStarlet would look like:

```
xmlstarlet ed \
  --subnode '//wtc-server' -t elem -n wtc-import \
  --subnode '//wtc-server/wtc-import[last()]' -t elem -n name -v WTCImportedService-0-rap01 \
  --subnode '//wtc-server/wtc-import[last()]' -t elem -n resource-name -v XXXX01F \
  --subnode '//wtc-server/wtc-import[last()]' -t elem -n local-access-point -v lap01 \
  --subnode '//wtc-server/wtc-import[last()]' -t elem -n remote-access-point-list -v rap01 \
  --subnode '//wtc-server/wtc-import[last()]' -t elem -n remote-name -v XXXX01F \
  <in.xml >out.xml
```

(code tested without any `xmlns` definitions, since the original version of the question didn't contain any).